# Can't check if site is up or down because of SSL

Tags: php, http, url, ssl, curl

So I'm tryign to check if a site is up or down with curl. So here's my logic

- Strip URL of protocol and anything else, leave just host. `example.com`
- Add `http` protocol to URL, then follow redirect with curl

So here's some code

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    $domain = $_GET['url'];

    //Clean up domain
    $input = trim($domain, '/');

    // If scheme not included, prepend it
    if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input)) {
        $input = 'http://' . $input;
    }

    $urlParts = parse_url($input);

    // remove www
    $domain = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);

    function addhttp($domain) {
        if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $domain)) {
            $domain = "http://" . $domain;
        }
        return $domain;
    }
    $domain = addhttp($domain);

    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

}
```

And my function to check if the site is up or down

```
function isDomainAvailible($domain){
    if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        return false;
    }

    $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

    curl_close($curlInit);

    if($response)return true;

    return false;
}
```

Now the issue is, when I do a website that has SSL, therefore having a redirect, I always seem to get that the site is up, even though it's down. Any ideas? Is my logic in the right direction?

Comment: Why do you strip out the protocol in the first place?

Comment: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` does exactly what the name implies. It *follows* redirects. Remove that.

Comment: @Barmar I see no stripping of protocols. Rather an appending of them, if they're not present.

Comment: So I only get the actual host, and not a long URL @Barmar

Comment: That's why you remove the path, why do you remove the protocol?

Comment: So the user can simply enter `example.com` instead of the rest @Barmar

Comment: Why? I'm trying to follow them so I can get to the true page @LinusKleen

Answer (score 1):

```
function isDomainAvailible($domain){
    if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        return false;
    }

    $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);

    $m=true;
    if(curl_exec($curlInit) === false){ $m=false; echo "Error: ".curl_error($curlInit);}
    curl_close($curlInit);


    return $m;
}
```

Comment: This returns invalid responses, telling me that some sites are down, when in reality they're not.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `TRUE`.

That option does what its name implies: it *follows* redirection headers sent by the site. You'll need to remove this option (or explicitly set it to `FALSE`) to "validate" the actual URL.

On a side note: you're stripping the `www.` part of the domain name regardless of whether there is an actual DNS `A` record pointing to the domain name with the same IP address. You *might* be getting an answer from a different machine when doing that.